# How to create master/detail view in Microsoft dynamic CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Can anybody please show me step by step how to create Master/Detail(Parent/Child) view in Microsoft Dynamic CRM 4.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put an IFrame on the Parent entity that shows all the Children entities.  This post should get you pointed in the right direction:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm/thread/fc98391d-d8d5-4e2b-a595-1d525d475c84