# Dynamics CRM 2011 Connections

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

The company I work for has clients which have various businesses but which are owned by the same person. The different businesses have separate contracts and we have linked the two accounts by a connection.

Now, when a case regarding one of the businesses is created, we want all the contracts of both businesses to show up under 'Contracts'. Is this possible?

Ex:  Business A  - Contract A

Business B - Contract B

Case for Business A : Available contracts: Contract A , Contract B ( since the owner is the same we want both of them to show)

Comment: you can inject Fetch code into a view.  The process is messy and not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

It is, but it would probably take some development.  You would need some sort of html/silverlight xap web resource or an iframed web application to retrieve and dynamically load the contracts of all the account connections on the account form.  The web application would need to take into account the relationship of the parent account to the child accounts and it may be easier instead of using connections, just to make them child accounts to the parent account.  That's how its done pre-2011.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can suggest something here.

1. Have that 'person' as master Customer (record of type account), and have all the businesses (A, B) as child Customers (records of type account).
2. Now create an advanced find view to list all the contracts for 'master' customer
3. Expose it in a grid. (read more here [How to create master/detail view in Microsoft dynamic CRM 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716830/how-to-create-master-detail-view-in-microsoft-dynamic-crm-4-0))